# How to verify certificates (not self signed) using PHP

Tags: php, ssl, openssl

I have received two files and I am supposed to validate using **PHP**!

> One file starts with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`
>
> and ends with `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`
>
> The second file starts with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`
>
> and ends with `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

Kindly note that the domains are not online yet but I need to find out how to get the domain names by using these two files.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. using the `openssl` commands on a linux machine, there doesn't appear to be a way of retrieving the domain details from a certificate. If you can't do it with the command line tools, you certainly won't be able to do it in PHP. One question - why do you need to this?

Comment: @DaveyBoy I need this to verify uploaded certificate files.

Comment: In that case, use the command line openssl verify commands.

Comment: Openssl can absolutely dump certificate details to the screen. To get the subject name of a certificate: `openssl x509 -in certificateFileName.pem -noout -text | grep "Subject: "`

Comment: @dodexahedron thanks a lot for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I found is to use this in PHP:

> $contents = file_get_contents($certificate_file_path);
>
> $parsed = openssl_x509_parse($contents);
>
> print_r($parsed);

This will give you every associated information in an array format.